# c# xml - show only one item/node if item names are the same

Tags: c#, xml, for-loop, foreach

This is .NET 2.0 project. First of all the xml i what to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>TECH_Y_Category</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>TECH_File</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>TECH_File</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>TECH_Version</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>TECH_Group</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>TECH_D_Group_File_Version</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>TECH_Layout</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>TECH_File</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>CK_List</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>CK_Vote</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>CK_List</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>CK_Score</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>TECH_Page</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>TECH_Page</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
  <diagramer>
    <PKTABLE_NAME>CK_List</PKTABLE_NAME>
    <FKTABLE_NAME>Comments</FKTABLE_NAME>
  </diagramer>
</DocumentElement>
```

As you can see some PKTABLE_NAME values are the same.
Im looping through that xml using code below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode items in diagramTables)
{
  string pkTable = items["PKTABLE_NAME"].InnerText.Replace("_",@"\_");
  string fkTable = items["FKTABLE_NAME"].InnerText.Replace("_",@"\_");

  sb.Append(pkTable);
  sb.Append(" got ");
  sb.Append( fkTable + Environment.NewLine);

}
```

Its not exaclly what i want to achive. I want to have all  values but only once (i dont want to repeat them). after all i want to write sometingingh like this from xml above:

- TECH_Y_Category *got*
  TECH_File
- TECH_File *got* TECH_Version
- TECH_Group *got* TECH_D_Group_File_Version
- TECH_Layout *got* TECH_File
- **CK_List *got* CK_Vote | CK_Score | Comments**
- TECH_Page *got* TECH_Page

I hope you understand what im trying to achieve.

EDIT.

Code from Morawski worked perfectly for me so problem is solved ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (XmlNode items in diagramTables)
{
  string pkTable = items["PKTABLE_NAME"].InnerText.Replace("_",@"\_");
  string fkTable = items["FKTABLE_NAME"].InnerText.Replace("_",@"\_");
  if (!dict.ContainsKey(pkTable))
  {
    dict.Add(pkTable, new List<string>());
  }
  if (!dict[pkTable].Contains(fkTable))
  {
      dict[pkTable].Add(fkTable);
  }
}
sb.Append("========================================================="); // making it easier for you
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in dict)
{
  sb.Append(kvp.Key);
  sb.Append(" got ");
  sb.AppendLine(String.Join("|", kvp.Value.ToArray()));
}
sb.Append("========================================================="); // making it easier for you
```

Comment: As i said its a .NET 2.0 project ;). I cant use var keyword. There is other solution to that ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there was no `var` prior to .NET 3.0. I updated my code accordingly. `var` is nothing really, just shorthand notation for the same thing.

Comment: Thx :). I tested this and reasult is like that -> please look first comment.

Comment: That's physically impossible. A dictionary can't contain duplicate keys. I bet that only last 6 lines from the printed output actually come from my code; most probably you forgot to delete your own `sb.Append`s from the first `foreach` loop or something. Just make sure you have the right code.

Comment: See the update. Do you get duplicate table names _in_ _between_ those double lines?

Comment: I do apologize. I was writing result to file using File.AppendAllText but inside foreach loop. When i placed that code outside of the loop its working lika a charm :). Once again thank very much. Dziękuje ;)

Comment: Yeah I knew there must have been something mixed up. Nie ma za co ;) Glad it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Store result in a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) of [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19):

```
var nodes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

foreach (XmlNode childNode in document.ChildNodes)
{
    if(nodes.ContainsKey(childNode.Name))
        nodes[childNode.Name].Add(childNode.InnerText);
    else
        nodes.Add(childNode.Name, new List<string> {childNode.InnerText});
}

// and printing

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    string values = node.Value.Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + ("|" + s));
    Console.WriteLine(node.Key + " gots " + values);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much the same solution as mine, your code by some coincidence even contains `kvp.Value.ToArray()`, even though your iteration variable is not named `kvp` at all (only mine is) :))

Comment: ;) oooops! yes. I'm a lasy tipper. i add my way